# What's wrong with this jquery resizable function?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to use the new jquery-ui, and all but the resizable function seem to work. The handles don't seem to appear anywhere. Can anyone figure out why?

http://victor.hwanger.com/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to include the jQuery-UI CSS references:

http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css